# Rails serialization error for async geocoding with ahoy gem using mongoid

Tags: mongoid, ruby-on-rails-5, delayed-job, rails-activejob, ahoy

I have a Rails 5 app, running both a postgresql DB for application data and MongoDB ([mongoid](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid)) for analytics, generated by the fantastic [ahoy](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy) gem.

Everything works great until I switch to asynchronous geocoding in `config/initializers/ahoy.rb`, which generates the error below:

```
ActiveJob::SerializationError (Unsupported argument type: Visit):
```

The app is using [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job), for background processing.

I there a workaround for this issue, or is this caused by incompatibility between mongoid and delayed_job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the GlobalId mixin to your model

```
class Visit
  include GlobalID::Identification
end
```

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewKane.

This helps in creating the job, but now I'm getting a new error when delayed_job looks to perform the geocoding:

`ActiveJob::DeserializationError: Error while trying to deserialize arguments:
Document(s) not found for class Visit with id(s) #<BSON::Binary:0x000000090f6f00>`

I've tried to see what could be causing this, and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39055708/using-sidekiq-for-active-job-and-getting-activejobdeserializationerror) on stack exchange:

What do you think about passing the id into the perform method?